# GCM Notification not register for token and not receiving notifications

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

This is my appdelegate where is my notification implementations goes on. Sometimes I register with token and token is received. But not receiving notifications. But some time there is no registration with token at all. This is my code below.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import RxSwift
//import Firebase
//import Messages

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message.shopflow.key"
    var window: UIWindow?
    let userdefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
//        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
//        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        registerForPushNotifications()
        checkReachability()
        checkRegisterdUser()




        // Check whether the app has opened from a notification or a normal launch
        //crashing code
//        let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary
//        if remoteNotif != nil {
//            let notifName = remoteNotif?["aps"] as! String
//            print("Notification: \(notifName )")
//        }else{
//            print("Not remote")
//        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        checkReachability()
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        checkReachability()
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        checkReachability()
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // check connectivity
    func checkReachability(){
        if ReachabilityHelper.shared.checkNetworkReachability(){

        }else{
            showNetworkAlert()
        }
    }



    // show network alert
    func showNetworkAlert(){

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Error", message:"An active internet connection is needed to use this app.Please make sure you are connected and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:  NSLocalizedString("Retry", comment: ""), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in

            if ReachabilityHelper.shared.checkNetworkReachability(){
                //print("Connected")

            }else{
               // print("Not connected")
                self.showNetworkAlert()
            }

        }

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        window!.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func checkRegisterdUser(){

       // let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardIdentifier., bundle: <#T##Bundle?#>)

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Key.loginStatus){
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardIdentifier.home.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerIdentifiers.tabBar.rawValue) as! UITabBarController
            Constants.AppObjects.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc

           // self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {

//        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
//          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
//          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
//
//          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
//          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
//            options: authOptions,
//            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
//        } else {
//          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
//          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
//            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
//        }
//
//        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()



                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                        (granted, error) in
                        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

                        guard granted else { return }
                        self.getNotificationSettings()
                    }

    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }

//    private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UNNotificationSettings) {
////        if notificationSettings. != UIUserNotificationType() {
//        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
////      }
//    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        userdefaults.set("NA", forKey: "DEVICE_TOKEN")
        userdefaults.synchronize()
      print("Registration failed!")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }

        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
        userdefaults.set(token, forKey:"DEVICE_TOKEN")
        userdefaults.synchronize()

        _ = HomeViewModel().deviceToken().subscribe(onNext:{ message in

            if message == response.success.rawValue{
                //print("Signup done")
                print("new Device Token device registation")
            }else if message != ""{
               print("shopErrors:fail Device Token device registation")
                //print(alertMessage)
            }

        }).disposed(by: DisposeBag())

    }

//    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//
//        if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as! [NSObject : AnyObject]? {
//
//        }
//    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
//        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
      // handle your message
    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }

  func registerForPushNitfication(){
    registerForPushNotifications()
  }
}

//extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
//    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
//        let dataDic: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
//        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDic)
//
//        userdefaults.set(dataDic["token"], forKey:"DEVICE_TOKEN")
//        userdefaults.synchronize()
//
//        _ = HomeViewModel().deviceToken().subscribe(onNext:{ message in
//
//            if message == response.success.rawValue{
//                //print("Signup done")
//                print("shopErrors:new Device Token device registation")
//            }else if message != ""{
//               print("shopErrors:fail Device Token device registation")
//                //print(alertMessage)
//            }
//
//        }).disposed(by: DisposeBag())
//    }
//
//}
```

I register for APNs and enable push notifications and also background notification fetch capability. But I couldn't resolve this. Anyone can find an answer?

Comment: Still, using GCM in 2020?

Comment: This is an old project. Backend is not migrated for FCM yet mate